# Determining size of image when scraping in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have been researching a gem, 'hpricot', to scrape web pages. I am successful in retrieving image tags from the web page. However, I am in need of a solution to determining the image size of images on the web page.

I am thinking of using javascript to do this, but I am still thinking of how the approach would be.

Has anyone needed a similar solution just like this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a simpler / more efficient way of doing this, but from my knowledge, this could probably work:

1. Use `open-uri` to open the image
2. Use `Paperclip::Geometry` on the opened image to get the dimensions of the image.

Comment: I actually did it by using Paperclip::Geometry and open-uri. I didn't need to write the image bytes. If you can edit your answer, I can accept it.